# nlminb() function in R returns a NA/NaN function evaluation error - I tried to limit the parameter search space too

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to maximise the log likelihood of a function using `nlminb()` but get a

> "NA/NaN function evaluation" error.

I also tried to limit the parameter search space but the problem persists. Given below is the piece of code I am working with. How do i debug this - thanks for the help.

```
 ll1<-function(x)
{
a<-x[1]
b<-x[2]
return(
-(
8*log((a/(a+0))^b-(a/(a+1))^b)
+
6*log((a/(a+1))^b-(a/(a+2))^b)
+
2*log((a/(a+2))^b-(a/(a+3))^b)
+
16*log((a/(a+3))^b-(a/(a+4))^b)
+
8*log((a/(a+4))^b-(a/(a+5))^b)
+
7*log((a/(a+5))^b-(a/(a+6))^b)
+
3*log((a/(a+6))^b-(a/(a+7))^b)
+
2*log((a/(a+7))^b-(a/(a+8))^b)
+
5*log((a/(a+8))^b-(a/(a+9))^b)
+
3*log((a/(a+9))^b-(a/(a+10))^b)
+
5*log((a/(a+10))^b-(a/(a+11))^b)
+
2*log((a/(a+11))^b-(a/(a+12))^b)
+
1*log((a/(a+12))^b-(a/(a+13))^b)
+
4*log((a/(a+13))^b-(a/(a+14))^b)
+
3*log((a/(a+14))^b-(a/(a+15))^b)
+
6*log((a/(a+15))^b-(a/(a+16))^b)
+
9*log((a/(a+16))^b-(a/(a+17))^b)
+
4*log((a/(a+17))^b-(a/(a+18))^b)
+
2*log((a/(a+18))^b-(a/(a+19))^b)
+
0*log((a/(a+19))^b-(a/(a+20))^b)
+
0*log((a/(a+20))^b-(a/(a+21))^b)
+
1*log((a/(a+21))^b-(a/(a+22))^b)
+
0*log((a/(a+22))^b-(a/(a+23))^b)
+
4*log((a/(a+23))^b-(a/(a+24))^b)
+
1398*log(a/(a+24))^b
)
)
}

c<-nlminb(c(6,2),ll1,lower=c(0.01, 0.01), upper=c(1000,1000))
```

Comment: `a/(a+24)` is smaller than 1, then `log(a/(a+24))` is negative. Therefore `log(a/(a+24))^b` is `NaN`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I missed the brackets on the final term